# Computing and plotting a correlogram

Tags: data-visualization, matlab

I have a sample data for a spatial grid of size 20x20. I need to plot the correlogram of this grid of data to see how much they are correlated. Currently I have 400 data points for the 20x20 grid cells, one for each cell. How can I compute the correlogram to see the correlation?

Comment: @Gung, a correlogram is the spatial analog of a time series correlogram.  It's a single plot of correlation versus lag and lag is either a distance or a vector, depending on various assumptions.  It won't necessarily have 20 rows and 20 columns.  An efficient computational method is to multiply the FFTs of the array; see, e.g., http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0098300401000073.

Comment: @whuber, thanks for letting me know. Unfortunately, I know almost nothing about spatial statistics. (You may have noticed that I mostly answer simple questions on CV.) I will delete my previous comment.

Comment: Just to clarify, what sort of spatial data?  Do you mean you have 400 single values, and they are arranged in the grid?  Or is it 400 variables, each with multiple measurements?

Comment: Yeah I have a grid of 20x20 cells and there is a measurement for each cell. So a total of 400. How can I use this data to plot the correlogram and see how much they are correlated

Comment: For grids, using MatLab: http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/f21-17064.html.  For irregular point data, using R: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/spatial/html/correlogram.html.  (To make the example work, include the line `library(spatial)`.)

Comment: I didn't get it. Why do we need fourier transform for correlogram

Comment: You don't: but it's *much* faster and easier to compute, especially in an environment like Matlab that already provides a discrete FFT.  If you like, feel free to compute a correlogram (or autocorrelation function or variogram) directly from the definition.

Comment: But actually, I don't know how to use FFT to actually get the correlogram. Currently I have a data for the 20x20 grid that is 400 readings for the corresponding grid. How to apply FFT on it to get the correlogram. I mean what is the procedure?