# How to plot a correlogram

Tags: correlation, matlab, autocorrelation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computing and plotting a correlogram](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28942/computing-and-plotting-a-correlogram)

I have spatial data for a grid of size 20x20. I wanted to know how I can plot a correlogram to see how much the data are correlated spatially.